# Find matching and non matching recs panda

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have 2 csv files with data given in this fashion. How can i perform a basic matching and produce a result like the output. I'm matching based on the websites field. that's the key i'm using here for matching.

I tried [Efficiently find matching rows (based on content) in a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25028113/efficiently-find-matching-rows-based-on-content-in-a-pandas-dataframe)
and
https://macxima.medium.com/python-retrieve-matching-rows-from-two-dataframes-d22ad9e71879

but i'm not getting my desired output. Any assistance would be helpful

```
file1.csv
| id | web_1  |
|----|------|
| 1  | google.com |
| 2  | microsoft.in |
| 3  | yahoo.uk |
| 4  | adobe.us |


file2.csv
| id | web_2 |
|----|-----|
|2| microsoft.in |
| 3  | yahoo.uk |
| 4  | adobe.us |


output 
| id | web_1  | web_2  |
|----|------|--------|
| 1  | google.com | |
| 2  | microsoft.in | microsoft.in |
| 3  | yahoo.uk | yahoo.uk |
| 4  | adobe.us | adobe.us |
```

Comment: just merge on the `ids`? `pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['id'],how='outer')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: no , loookin to merge based on urls, can the same logic be used?

Comment: @Umar.H your code is giving more records i guess the records from file2 is also getting added to the final output. i want my final output count to remain the same and there should be na extra col for the urls from file2 like ( web_2) in the output. the code here isn't working that way

Comment: that's because you have duplicates in one of your dataframes.

Comment: please upload the raw contents of your original csv files and the code you tried. i can help fix your code.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68129873/find-matching-and-non-matching-recs-panda/68131832#comment120415982_68129873) if you want to merge the dataframes in a way where the result only includes rows where the merge keys match you can do an inner join.

[`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) uses `'inner'` as the default type of merge.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": [1, 2, 3, 4],
        "web_1": ["google.com", "microsoft.in", "yahoo.uk", "adobe.us"],
    }
)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": [2, 3, 4],
        "web_2": ["microsoft.in", "yahoo.uk", "adobe.us"],
    }
)

>>>  pd.merge(df1, df2)
   id         web_1         web_2
0   2  microsoft.in  microsoft.in
1   3      yahoo.uk      yahoo.uk
2   4      adobe.us      adobe.us
```

If you don't want to keep both web columns you can just drop one of them:

```
>>> pd.merge(df1, df2).drop(columns='web_2')
   id         web_1
0   2  microsoft.in
1   3      yahoo.uk
2   4      adobe.us
```

Drop and rename:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2).drop(columns='web_2').rename(columns={'web_1': 'web'})
   id           web
0   2  microsoft.in
1   3      yahoo.uk
2   4      adobe.us
```